# Coding a clicker game that can store and load data at will , but still continue the click counter after the page refresh

Tags: javascript

I'm new at coding and today for a few days I've tried to code a simple clicker game that has a counter in it, basically all you had to do was to click the image to increase your xp number and after 25 xp number you get 1 kill count from it, I've tried the localstorage setitem and get item, they're working flawlessly however after I refreshed the page and then clicked on the image again the counter reset from 1 I've tried a few thin

```html
<html>
    <head>
            <title> Menggokil Adventure </title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <p>XP: <span id="XP">0</span></p>
        <p>KillCount <span id="KillCount">0</span></p>
        <img src="gokil.jpg" height="256px" width="256px"  onclick="addToXP (1)">
        <br> 
        <button onclick="SAVE()">Save Game Gokil ini</button> <button onclick="LOAD()">Load Game Gokil ini</button>
    </body>
</html>
 
<script>
  var XP= 0 , checkXP;
  var KillCount=0;
    function addToXP(amount) { 
      XP = XP + (amount)
      document.getElementById("XP").innerHTML = XP;
      killCount(); 
    }

    function SAVE() {
      localStorage.setItem("XP", XP); console.log('XP', XP);
      localStorage.setItem("killcount", KillCount); console.log("killcount" , KillCount)
    } 
    function LOAD() {
      var XP = localStorage.getItem("XP");
      var KillCount = localStorage.getItem("killcount");
      document.getElementById("XP").innerHTML = XP;
      document.getElementById("KillCount").innerHTML = KillCount; 
      console.log("killcount", KillCount)
    } 

  function killCount() {
    if(XP % 25 === 0) {
      KillCount++ 
      document.getElementById("KillCount").innerHTML = KillCount;
  }
  function checkXP() {
      var XP = checkXP("XP"); }
      if (XP == "checkXP") {
          XP = "checkXP"
          setCookie("CheckXP", XP);
      }
      return parseInt(XP);
  }

</script>
```

gs however I'm still at a loss since I'm new, can anyone give me some leads for this problem?

Comment: Call `LOAD()` on page load.

Comment: i'm sorry how can i do that specifically ? @CherryDT

Comment: For example you write `LOAD();` before the closing `</script>` tag. This will call the function when the page is loaded.

Comment: In your LOAD() function remove the var from in front of the XP variable. Then your code might work properly. You are defining a local variable and thus the more "global" one is not being set as you wish. So just removing the var is most probably going to save your day. (Same goes for KillCount)

Comment: hi i've tried to delete the var as you suggest me to do , well as the counter itself it didn't reset when i click it however it won't continue the number as if from 25 into 26 but it would go like 251 2511 25111 and so on , any more suggestion about this and thanks for the advice earlier @jPO

Comment: *"... but it would go like 251 2511 25111"* ...  Does the OP see a pattern? It's due to adding the number value `1` to a string value of `'25` (, `'251`, `'2511`, and so forth). Values are stored as strings. Thus one needs to explicitly parse them into number values after retrieving it from the storage.

Comment: Then please add parseInt around the localStorage.getItem("XP") in the LOAD function to make sure the number is not parsed as a string.

Comment: thanks for pointing out @PeterSeliger , i understand now however i might be a little a little bit slow on the uptake , as for me i've tried to search about it however none of them mentioned about this parseint , guess that i still have a lot to learn :D

Comment: @YueXinYue ... no problem. Most of us started like this. Keep going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments I will formulate an answer.

If you want to use the globally defined counters (like the `XP` or `killCount`) even after you `LOAD()` then you have to overwrite the variables. This is possible if you access them from the `LOAD()` function. What you are doing is defining new local variables within the `LOAD()` context. For overriding the values within the globally defined variables, omit the `var` keyword from the variables `XP` and `killCount` and make sure, that the variable read out of the localContext gets parsed correctly as a number.

```
function LOAD() {
      XP = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("XP"));
      KillCount = localStorage.getItem("killcount");
      document.getElementById("XP").innerHTML = XP;
      document.getElementById("KillCount").innerHTML = KillCount; 
      console.log("killcount", KillCount)
    }
```

This should bring you up to speed.

Comment: wow , now it's working , thank you very much i'm a little bit on the slow side about this whole code things , as i was still on the learning stages . once again thanks :D

Comment: Please do not forget marking the answer as the chosen one if it helped you :) And you are welcome!

Comment: ok i've already marked it thanks again :D